# UK Visa Bronze Premium Service

Tags: visas, uk

How many days on average does the Bronze Premium Service take? Does it take more than 7 working days? When I pay for the service, can I just walk in?

Comment: Just walk in where?

Comment: https://www.vfsglobal.co.uk/usa/user_pay_services.html

Answer (score 5):

The priority visa service for those in the US to apply for a UK visa is through [VFS Global](https://www.vfsglobal.co.uk/usa/applicationcentre.html)

Note that the [Bronze Premium Service](http://vfsglobal.co.uk/usa/pdf/Bronze.pdf) indicates Standard Processing: that means within the VHS offices; an appointment is not required but there is an additional fee for walk-ins, as well as additional fees for courier services to expedite turn-around times.

> Bronze Premium Service Package
>
> Price: USD 235 (+ additional fee of USD 50 if applying without appointment)
>
> This service package is exclusively available at the VFS Premium Application Centres in Atlanta, Boston, Chicago, Houston, Los Angeles, Miami, San Francisco, Seattle, and Washington DC. For more details on the services included with this package, [please click here](https://www.vfsglobal.co.uk/usa/applicationcentre.html#3) to visit our Premium Application Centre page.
>
> This service is available Monday-Friday, either with or without a pre-scheduled appointment (additional $50 fee applies if you do not have a pre-scheduled appointment)

The [UKVI](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/usa-apply-for-a-uk-visa/apply-for-a-uk-visa-in-the-usa) description:

> This is an optional service where you can pay an extra fee to fast track your application and have your visa application processed ahead of non priority applications.
>
> The super priority and premium visa services enable customers to receive a decision on their application within 24 hours.