# Bronze premium package service

Tags: visas, vfs-global

I was forced to pay for one of these premium packages for a skilled worker visa(there are no other options at this time) and due to the cost I chose bronze. VFS Global does not explain the features of any of it's premium packages.  What do I get for paying for a bronze package in terms of processing times.

Comment: It seems a scam

Comment: Who forced you and how?

Comment: Skilled worker visa sounds like something that would belong on the [Expats site](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/) rather than here. But if you do post it there, you will have to include much more detail. Which country's visa are you applying for? Where are you applying for it?

Comment: Related question https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/99388/uk-visa-bronze-premium-service

Comment: Does this answer your question? [UK Visa Bronze Premium Service](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/99388/uk-visa-bronze-premium-service)